# Find the limit points of a complex sequence

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I need to find limit points of the following sequence
$a_n=(2\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-i})^n - (i \cdot \frac{1}{n+1})$
I already simplified it a bit:
$a_n = (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{3}{2} \cdot i)^n-\frac{i}{n+1}$
I know that I need to find limits of subsequences of this sequence but which subsequences and how many should I choose?
Is it possible that $a_n$ has its own limit?

Comment: How did you simplify to obtain that second expression for $a_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-i}=\frac{2(\sqrt{3}+i)}{4}=\sqrt{3}/2 +i/2=e^{i \pi/6}.$$

This form makes it much easier to find subsequences that converge to different limits. For example, if we take $b_n=a_{12n}$, the subsequence converge to 1. If we take $c_n=a_{12n+1}$, the subsequence converges to $e^{i\pi/6}$.

Comment: How do I obtain $\sqrt{3}/2 +i/2=e^{i \pi/6}$?
Is Euler's identity applied here?

Comment: Yes. $e^{i\pi/6}=\cos(\pi/6)+i\sin(\pi/6)$.